# phpsessid in cookie over https

Tags: php, session, session-cookies, sessionid

in my local WAMP server, when I call `session_start()` the session-id is being set in the cookie as follows and `var_dump($_COOKIE)` gives the following.

```
array
  'PHPSESSID' => string 'qg8nrlpdtgb391386lhghgv727' (length=26)
```

so when I call session_start() again, my previous session is resumed.

but when I deployed the same code to my web-server, the PHPSESSID is not being set in the cookie. So as a result, every time I call `session_start(),` a new session is getting created instead of resume the previous session.

Can anyone please tell me a possible cause of the problem. *Do we have to explicitly set the PHPSESSID to the cookie?*

*Also, In my local(WAMP) I **dont** have https, but the web-server where I pushed the code is https. Is this a problem?*

I am stuck with this for almost 3 days now.

Thanks in advance.
Kanna

Comment: Have you checked [session.use_cookies]( http://www.php.net/manual/en/session.configuration.php#ini.session.use-cookies) on the server?

Comment: Also http://us3.php.net/manual/en/function.session-set-cookie-params.php

Comment: do we have to set cookie params every time we make a call to session_start.. can you please explain me then how it is working on my WAMP server without setting cookie params...

Comment: please copy the following single line into a PHP file, and tell us the line that gets outputed:
`<?php $path = session_save_path(); if (is_dir($path)) echo (is_readable($path) ? 'path is readable' : 'path is not readable').' and '.(is_writable($path) ? 'path is writable' : 'path is not writable'); else die('path is not a directory'); echo (ini_get('session.use_cookies') ? ' and use cookies are set' : ' and cookies are not set');`

Comment: Oops, I just saw you solved your problem

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had called session_start() immediately after html < head > tag. This was the problem. When I moved the session_start() method before the html head tag, the problem was solved.

Thanks everyone for your help.
Kanna

Answer (score 2):

Looks like session handling is configured differently on this webserver. You should compare the values set in the php.ini file under the session-section.

Especially:

1. Is `session.use_cookies` set to 1?
2. Does `session.save_path` point to a valid directory, where the webserver user has write permission

See here for a full list of session-settings:
http://de3.php.net/manual/de/session.configuration.php